# How do I explode this column of type array json in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to explode this column into multiple columns, but it seems there is an issue with the datatype even though I have specified it to be an array datatype.

This is what the column looks like:

```
        Column_x

[[{"Key":"a","Value":"40000.0"},{"Key":"b","Value":"0.0"},{"Key":"c","Value":"0.0"},{"Key":"f","Value":"false"},{"Key":"e","Value":"ADB"},{"Key":"d","Value":"true"}]]

[[{"Key":"a","Value":"100000.0"},{"Key":"b","Value":"1.5"},{"Key":"c","Value":"1.5"},{"Key":"d","Value":"false"},{"Key":"e","Value":"Rev30"},{"Key":"f","Value":"true"},{"Key":"g","Value":"48600.0"},{"Key":"g","Value":"0.0"},{"Key":"h","Value":"0.0"}],[{"Key":"i","Value":"100000.0"},{"Key":"j","Value":"1.5"},{"Key":"k","Value":"1.5"},{"Key":"l","Value":"false"},{"Key":"m","Value":"Rev30"},{"Key":"n","Value":"true"},{"Key":"o","Value":"48600.0"},{"Key":"p","Value":"0.0"},{"Key":"q","Value":"0.0"}]]
```

To something like this:

```
Key   Value
a     10000
b     200000
.
.
.
.
a     100000.0
b     1.5
```

This is my work so far:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = ArrayType(ArrayType(StructType([StructField("Key", StringType()),
                                    StructField("Value", StringType())])))

kn_sx = kn_s\
  .withColumn("Keys", F.explode((F.from_json("Column_x", schema))))\
  .withColumn("Key", col("Keys.Key"))\
  .withColumn("Values", F.explode((F.from_json("Column_x", schema))))\
  .withColumn("Value", col("Values.Value"))\
  .drop("Values")
```

Here is the error:

`` AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'jsontostructs(`Column_x`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, '`Column_x`' is of array<array<struct<Key:string,Value:string>>> type ``

Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

refer [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.get_json_object) for documentation of get_json_object

```
>>> data = [("1", '''{"f1": "value1", "f2": "value2"}'''), ("2", '''{"f1": "value12"}''')]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("key", "jstring"))
>>> df.select(df.key, get_json_object(df.jstring, '$.f1').alias("c0"), \
...                   get_json_object(df.jstring, '$.f2').alias("c1") ).collect()
[Row(key=u'1', c0=u'value1', c1=u'value2'), Row(key=u'2', c0=u'value12', c1=None)]
```

Comment: I get the same error `AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'get_json_object('Column_x, '$.Key')' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, 'Column_x' is of array<array<struct<Key:string,Value:string>>>`

Comment: try explode(array(
  get_json_object($"Payment", "$[0]")

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to make it work:

```
# Took out a single array element

df = df.withColumn('Column_x', F.col('Column_x.MetaData.Parameters').getItem(0))
# can be modified for additional array elements

# Used Explode on the dataframe to make it work
df = df\
  .withColumn("Keys", F.explode(F.col("Column_x")))\
  .withColumn("Key", col("Keys.Key"))\
  .withColumn("Value", col("Keys.Value"))\
  .drop("Keys")\
  .dropDuplicates()
```

I hope it finds anyone looking for help with this problem.